# Can I trigger subclass's member function from constructor of parent class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, coffeescript, super

```
class Person {
    contructor() {
        this.someSubclassMember();
    }
}

class Student {
    contructor() {
        super();
        this.someSubclassMember.bind(this); 
    }

    someSubclassMember() {

    }
}
```

I know I can define protected for somSubclassMember but I would like to iterate over subclasses prototype from parent class?

Is this feasible?
Thank you

PS: I saw its feasible in coffeescript. Here's the coffeescript compiled code

```
  module.exports = ProviderOS = (function(superClass) {
    extend(ProviderOS, superClass);

    function ProviderOS() {
      this.doInternalGetJobCollection = bind(this.doInternalGetJobCollection, this);
      this.doCreateJob = bind(this.doCreateJob, this);
      this.doCreateOnetimeJob = bind(this.doCreateOnetimeJob, this);
      this.doCreateHourlyJob = bind(this.doCreateHourlyJob, this);
      this.doCreateDailyJob = bind(this.doCreateDailyJob, this);
      this.doExecuteJob = bind(this.doExecuteJob, this);
      this.doGetServerInformation = bind(this.doGetServerInformation, this);
      this.getBaseName = bind(this.getBaseName, this);
      this.onInit = bind(this.onInit, this);
      return ProviderOS.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

In this case, I can access subclass member from super class.
But typescript required to call super before accessing this.

Comment: You can decalare the method as abstract, but calling it in the constructor is not a good idea. The method will run before the derived class constructor (body of the constructor and field initialization) leading to all sorts of wierd and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
The superclass has a member function called(init) and subclass overrides it. In this case, superclass do init() is to call init of subclass.
From subclass, I can use it as a constructor of subclass.